# The bot does not write in a private message Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to make the bot write to the **BOT** through the **mention** and through the **ID**.

Now it only works via **ID**

```
    client.on("message", async (message) => {
      if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
      const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(" ");
      const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
      const target = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
      const { guild } = message;
      const { name, region, memberCount, owner, afkTimeout } = guild;
      const icon = guild.iconURL();
      const User = client.users.cache.get(`${args[0]}`);
      const time = args.slice(1).join(" ");
      const reason = args.slice(2).join(" ");
      if (command === "mute") {
          client.users.fetch(args[0]).then((target) => {
            target.send({
              embed: {
                title: `${User.username}`,
                description: `**Miderator:** ${message.author} \n**Time:** ${args[1]} \n**Reason:** ${reason}`,
                thumbnail: {
                  url: `${User.avatarURL()}`,
                },
              },
            });
          }); }});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like

```
let person = message.mentions.users.first().id || args[0]
 client.users.fetch(person).then(target => {
            target.send({
              embed: {
                title: `${User.username}`,
                description: `**Miderator:** ${message.author} \n**Time:** ${args[1]} \n**Reason:** ${reason}`,
                thumbnail: {
                  url: `${User.avatarURL()}`,
                },
              },
            });
          });
```